# What is the relation between normal extension and separable extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the relation between normal extension and separable extension?
Let F be the algebraic extension of K, if F is a separable extension of K,if and only if F is a normal extension of K? is this correct?

Answer (score 37):

**Neither implies the other.** So, there exist [separable extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_extension) that are not [normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_extension), and normal extensions that are not separable.

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$ is a separable extension that is not normal.
It is separable because [any extension of characteristic zero fields is separable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_field), but it is not normal because (for example) not all algebraic conjugates of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ lie in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ (its conjugates are $\zeta_3\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\zeta_3^2\sqrt[3]{2}$ where $\zeta_3$ is a cube root of unity; these are complex numbers, while $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})\subset\mathbb{R}$).

$\mathbb{F}_p(\sqrt[p]{T})/\mathbb{F}_p(T)$ is a normal extension that is not separable.
It is normal because $\mathbb{F}_p(\sqrt[p]{T})$ is the splitting field of $x^p-T\in \mathbb{F}_p(T)[x]$, but it is not separable because the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[p]{T}$ is $x^p-T=(x-\sqrt[p]{T})^p$ which does not have distinct roots.

A field extension $L/K$ that is both normal and separable is called a *Galois extension*.